# How to convert the format of inserted datetime in Informix?

Tags: datetime, informix

I insert my date/time data into a CHAR column in the format: '`6/4/2015 2:08:00 PM`'.
I want that this should get automatically converted to format: 
'`2015-06-04 14:08:00`' so that it can be used in a query because the format of DATETIME is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fffff`.

How to convert it?

Comment: When you say you "insert my datetime in format: `'6/4/2015 2:08:00 PM'`". what does that actually mean?  Do you have a CHAR or VARCHAR column that holds that format?  Or do you have a program which contains data in that format as a string and you want to insert it into an Informix DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND column, or something else?  Which language are you using?  You probably need to look up the [`TO_DATE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1543.htm) function.

Comment: I have data in my table in this format. So when i run a query to get specific data by date then I put this date but it doesnt accept it as it is DATETIME column. So I want that user puts date in '6/4/2015 2:08:00 PM' format and it changes to the DATETIME format as is required and query gets implemented then. I am using Informix only. How to use TO_DATE function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've stored the data in a string format (CHAR or VARCHAR), you have to decide how to make it work as a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND value.  For computational efficiency, and for storage efficiency, it would be better to store the value as a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND value, converting it on input and (if necessary) reconverting on output.  However, if you will frequently display the value without doing computations (including comparisons or sorting) it, then maybe a rococo locale-dependent string notation is OK.

The key function for converting the string to a DATETIME value is [`TO_DATE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1543.htm).  You also need to look at the [`TO_CHAR`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1542.htm) function because that documents the format codes that you need to use, and because you'll use that to convert a DATETIME value to your original format.

Assuming the column name is `time_string`, then you need to use:

```sql
TO_DATE(time_string, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %x')  -- What goes in place of x?
```

to convert to a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND — or maybe DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE — value (which will be further manipulated as if by EXTEND as necessary).

I would personally almost certainly convert the database column to DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND and, when necessary, convert to the string format on output with `TO_CHAR`.  The column name would now be `time_value` (for sake of concreteness):

```sql
TO_CHAR(time_value, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %x')  -- What goes in place of x?
```

The manual pages referenced do not immediately lead to a complete specification of the format strings.  I think a relevant reference is [`GL_DATETIME` environment variable](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_085.htm), but finding that requires more knowledge of the arcana of the Informix product set than is desirable (it is *not* the first thing that should spring to anyone's mind — not even mine!).  If that's correct (it probably is), then one of `%p` and `%r` should be used in place of `%x` in my examples.  I have to get Informix (re)configured on my machine to be able to test it.